# Working Collaborative with Other Departments

Tags: management, manager, teamwork, collaboration

My team has owned a marketing a project for about a year now that the marketing department would like to start having more ownership in and collaborate in. We owned it by default because no one their team ever did anything with it. The project manager has always resided on my team. As much as I would like to work collaboratively on it I feel like we still need a project manager though the marketing leader is reluctant to have someone as the project manager. My question would be is it wrong to want this process to stay on my team? Is it wrong to believe we need a project manager or champion who owns the process? My direct report believes that the process should be on our team and that it does need a champion or pm? How do I get the marketing leader on board to keep things as is?

Answer (score 1):

I worked at a large corporation once where the marketing department managed to take control of a large portion of the IT budget, as IT was a slow, mid-range (AS/400) group of developers who had difficulty delivering modern e-Business projects in an Agile way (at a time where Agile "expectations" existed before Agile was used to deliver projects - hope that makes sense).  This situation descended into a corporate squabble as there was board level support for marketing (they could outsource development), but IT's reputation was in the toilet.   The reason I bring this up is I can see the same situation brewing here.  All I can say is everyone needs to be on the same team with respect to delivering value to the business and power struggles are going to impede that

Answer (score 0):

#### Consider proposing the use of the DSDM Agile methodology.

DSDM is an Agile methodology that builds the business aspects of IT into the project with clearly defined roles for the IT and business personnel; the marketing staff here would be classified into the “business” roles here, though it’s possible that not all business roles would be filled by people from marketing (the Business Sponsor role is often filled by the CEO, for instance).

Here is a page that discusses the specific details of the DSDM roles and their responsibilities: https://agile-mercurial.com/2019/04/03/dsdm-project-management-roles-and-responsibilities/amp/